# SwiftUI wrapping UITableViewCell into UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

When I have UITableViewCell examples

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { 
  ...
}
```

that is self-sizing table view cell i.e. has constraints attached to all edges

and then wrap this cell into SwiftUI `UIViewRepresentable`
in order to use it in SwiftUI `List` o `LazyVStack`

Should it still autosize and have an appropriate size height that fits its content (like text) or do I need to use `.frame(height: )` in order to set its size

```
struct MyTableViewItem: UIViewRepresentable { 
   func makeUIView() -> some UIView { 
      MyTableViewCell()
   } 
}
```

I've thought it will autosize but seems to have problem with it.

I consider maybe my custom cell has some bug that prevents it from sizing or should I use some boilerplate to make it sized correctly.

If I am using frame() then in spite of its height to be sufficient the text inside this cell is still cut off.

Comment: List wraps into cells automatically all content that you pass to it.

Comment: You'll have a hard time with this approach. Make a UIViewControllerRepresentable instead and include the table cells in a table view (that's in a view controller).

Comment: entire table view also doesn't work correctly it randomly 1 of 10 times is cutting off content at the bottom. I think cells should autosize well, maybe some constraints are broken in UIKit and it is the reason they are laying out wrongly. I rewrite this cells into SwitUI. It will be the fastest approach.